# Registration via Chinese mobile number

Tags: python, twilio, registration, user-accounts

I am currently building a website intended for Chinese users.

I've noticed that almost all Chinese sites uses a phone number registration system:

Example 1
[image]

Example 2
[image]

This is the typical user flow:

1. User enter their phone number
2. User enter a captcha
3. Some Chinese equivalent of Twilio sends a text message to the number
4. User enters the special code

I find step 2 to be redundant since you can only register with a real phone number. However, I believe most sites do have to pay per text so that's a way for them to combat spammers.

They has to be an existing module that works with **Django/Flask/or any python framework**. Can anyone recommend me how this could be integrated to my site easily?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While Twilio doesn't have Chinese phone numbers, you can still use Twilio to send verfication messages like this. There's a good tutorial for [sending verification SMS messages in Django](http://atodorov.org/blog/2014/03/19/sms-pin-verification-with-twilio-and-django/) here. Or, if you'd like to try out [Authy](http://www.authy.com), which is a Twilio service designed particularly for verifying numbers and providing two factor authentication, there is a tutorial on the Twilio site on [phone verification in Flask with Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/account-verification/python/flask#1).

Let me know if this helps at all.